# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread (Firebase Database) in Andriod

Tags: android, multithreading, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

> FRAGMENT CODE

```
 ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2 : dataSnapshot1.child("Posts").getChildren()) {

                        try {

                            Model listdata = new Model();

                            Model for_post_details = dataSnapshot2.child("info").getValue(Model.class);

                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+dataSnapshot1.child("username").getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            String path = for_post_details.getPath();
                            String location = for_post_details.getLocation();
                            String caption = for_post_details.getCaption();
                            String username = "" + dataSnapshot1.child("username").getValue();

                            listdata.setPath(path);
                            listdata.setLocation(location);
                            listdata.setCaption(caption);
                            listdata.setUsername(username);

                            list.add(listdata);

                        } catch (Exception ignored) {
                        }
                    }

                }
                Adapter recyclerview = new Adapter(list, getActivity());
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
                recycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recycler.setAdapter(recyclerview);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
```

> ADAPTER CODE

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyHoder> {

    List<Model> list;
    Context context;

    public Adapter(List<Model> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyHoder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_trending,parent,false);
        MyHoder myHoder = new MyHoder(view);
        return myHoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHoder holder, int position) {
        Model mylist = list.get(position);
        holder.caption.setText(mylist.getCaption());
        holder.location.setText(mylist.getLocation());
        holder.username_top.setText(mylist.getUsername());
        holder.username_bottom.setText(mylist.getUsername());
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(mylist.getPath())
                .into(holder.image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    class MyHoder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView total_likes, caption, location, username_top, username_bottom;
        ImageView image;
        ImageButton like, share;

        public MyHoder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            total_likes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.total_likes);
            caption = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.caption);
            username_top = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_top);
            username_bottom = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_bottom);
            location = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            like = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
            share = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.share);

        }
    }
```

This is code which I'm using for building an app like Instagram.

The code is running fine, but UI is slow, scrolling is slow, the app get hangs.

and I got this message.

> I/Choreographer(1378): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be
>   doing too much work on its main thread.

what I'm doing wrong??

> and do you know which technique Instagram uses to display posts
>   smoothly?

Thanks

Comment: May be you are loading heavy images

Comment: @AswinPAshok images are just 15kb-17kb size.

Comment: are you fetching data on button click?

Comment: OnViewCreated when fragment loaded

Comment: try my code and check if it still hangs UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the above method inside `runOnUiThread()`, just copy this inside `onViewCreated()` in fragment

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2 : dataSnapshot1.child("Posts").getChildren()) {

                            try {

                                Model listdata = new Model();

                                Model for_post_details = dataSnapshot2.child("info").getValue(Model.class);

                                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+dataSnapshot1.child("username").getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                String path = for_post_details.getPath();
                                String location = for_post_details.getLocation();
                                String caption = for_post_details.getCaption();
                                String username = "" + dataSnapshot1.child("username").getValue();

                                listdata.setPath(path);
                                listdata.setLocation(location);
                                listdata.setCaption(caption);
                                listdata.setUsername(username);

                                list.add(listdata);

                            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    Adapter recyclerview = new Adapter(list, getActivity());
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                    recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
                    recycler.setAdapter(recyclerview);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**
Another method is to use `AsyncTask`

copy this code outside `onViewCreated()`

```
private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading please wait..");
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings)
    {
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2 : dataSnapshot1.child("Posts").getChildren()) {

                        try {

                            Model listdata = new Model();

                            Model for_post_details = dataSnapshot2.child("info").getValue(Model.class);

                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+dataSnapshot1.child("username").getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            String path = for_post_details.getPath();
                            String location = for_post_details.getLocation();
                            String caption = for_post_details.getCaption();
                            String username = "" + dataSnapshot1.child("username").getValue();

                            listdata.setPath(path);
                            listdata.setLocation(location);
                            listdata.setCaption(caption);
                            listdata.setUsername(username);

                            list.add(listdata);

                        } catch (Exception ignored) {
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d("anyError", error.toString());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String lengthOfFile)
    {

               Adapter recyclerview = new Adapter(list, getActivity());
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
                recycler.setAdapter(recyclerview);

        if ((pDialog != null)  && (pDialog.isShowing()))
        {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

and inside `onViewCreated()` just call `new LoadData().execute();`

Comment: try second method. If it works then accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

addValueEventListener call constantly when ever data is changed that created ui to stuck try using addListenerForSingleValueEvent which will read the data only once and add a timer task to periodically update the data of your app it will only update data occasionally when timer is finished and will not stuck your ui

Comment: I've tried using "addListenerForSingleValueEvent" but nothing changed. Same Results.

Comment: Please check you are not using other threading operation at same time.

Comment: @jubinpatel I don’t know anything about threading. Please guide me.

Comment: post your entire activity.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan this is entire activity, rest code is just view initialisation.

Comment: ok now remove this line of code `recycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());` and test your app if it still freezes UI.

Comment: Still, same result freezes UI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161158/discussion-between-pranav-fulkari-and-mohammed-farhan).